# How use library from Nuget?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Hay guys. I download some [library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN8Jr.png)  from Nuget. But I dont know how i must using it?Should I download [library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFNpt.png) from other sites or not?

Comment: Define "use". What do you want to do?

Comment: Nowadays, we all used NuGet to manage the dependencies of our (.NET) projects, instead of having to go to each dependency's download page to manually download the dll files and add them the project references, which is "the old way", of course you can still do that, but your time is not spent wisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to use a NuGet package in an ASP.NET Core web app is to add a `<PackageReference>` item your csproj file. This will have the effect of automatically downloading the NuGet package into your project during the build phase. Rather than editing the csproj file directly, you can instead use the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio, which provides a visual GUI where you can search for and install NuGet packages. Additionally you can also use the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio, which functions like a command line and issue a command like:

```
Install-Package PackageName
```

Both of these latter two methods have the same effect of adding a `<PackageReference>` item to your csproj file, so it really doesn't matter which way you do it.

Answer (score 0):

For `JavaScript Library` installed from `Nuget`, it will be installed to `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages`, and if you want to reference them in your project, you will need to copy them to `wwwroot\lib` manually or by task.

For using `JavaScript Library`, I would suggest you try [LibMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which will install the library directly to `wwwroot/lib`.